# Прозрачный фон в окне tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

У меня есть окно tkinter с текстом и с overrideredirect.
Мне надо что-бы было видно текст, но не было фона(был прозрачным) и текст был в верхнем углу(любом)

Answer (score 0):

Может быть стоит попробовать так:

> imageName blank
>       Blank the image; that is, set the entire image to have no data, so it will be displayed as transparent, and the background of whatever
>   window it is displayed in will show through.

https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.7/TkCmd/photo.htm

Применительно к Python это, наверное, должно выглядеть как-то так:

```
окно = Окно(.., bg = 'blank', ...)
```

Comment: А как это, установить изображение без данных?

Comment: @kotivas "как это" - я высказал **предположение**. В доке написано, что создавая любое окно можно задавать фон этого окна. Если указать в качестве фона специальное значение 'blank', то фон, вроде бы должен стать прозрачным. Надо просто попробовать.

Comment: попробовал такой код:
```
from tkinter import * 
top = Tk() 
C = Canvas(top, bg="blue", height=250, width=300) 
filename = PhotoImage(file ='blank') 
background_label = Label(top, image=filename) 
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1) 
C.pack() 
top.mainloop
```
Выдало ошибку что файл не найден.

Comment: Что-то я не понял Вашей идеи - как это сделать прозрачное фотоизображение?! Можно сделать прозрачный **фон** у окна. А любой **виджет** в Tkinter является окном. И у него можно задать фон. Вот я и предложил проверить, станет ли прозрачным фон у (к примеру) метки, если написать как-то так:  lbl = tkinter.Label(text="Test", fg="black", bg="blank")  ?